# ValueError: freq T not understood. Please report if you think this in error. (seasonal_decompose)

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

I was trying out seasonal_decompose to decompose my time series. The data is perfect time series with frequency of '2T' i.e. 2 Minutes. From file tsatools.py (site-pkgs\statsmodels\tsa\tsatools.py), in line 655, I added the following.
_ elif freq == 'T':
return 6024752_
I added this from the following inference:
*Freq A means 1 year hence it returns 1.
Q means quaterly and hence returns 4
M means monthly and hence returns 12 and so on.
Therefore, T means per minute, hence 60247*365*

When I do the above, I get following error:
ValueError: Inferred frequency of index and frequency don't match. This function does not re-sample
From line 70 in seasonal.py (statsmodel\tsa\seasonal.py)
Because : variable freq is : <2 * Minutes>
And variable pfreq is 2T 524160.

I mean seasonal decompose should be able to decompose timeseries of 1min frequency, and something seems to have changed. Please have a look at it, and let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: This has been fixed in statsmodels master and will be changed in the upcoming release so it will be possible to override the default period length freq.

Answer (score 12):

I got the same problem, I think it's an internal problem since I test all the index data type. At the end, I tried this and it works.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
decompfreq = 6*12
decomposition = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(ts3_log.values,freq=decompfreq)
trend = decomposition.trend
```

decompfreq is calculated based on the time window, which is 10 mins, so the freqency actually is half a day.

Hope this would help you

Comment: If I understand correctly, does `freq` need to be the # of samples in a season? So if I had daily seasonality and my samples are every 5 minutes, then `freq = ((24*60)//5)`?

Comment: yup, I think so

Comment: What is that supposed to mean? Number of samples in a season? Am I supposed to know the season/seasons beforehand?

Comment: I don't understand. Then it's simply the len of my series?

Answer (score 3):

"You need to explicitly set the period when using data that does not have an obvious seasonality." - User [bashtage](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/4586#issuecomment-559402150).

If your data is in seconds, then try:

`sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(series, period = 60*60*24)` to represent a daily period.

Reference: the `statsmodels.tsa.tsatools` [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/tsatools.html) for `freq_to_period`.